# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How do I make an embed have a random color?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make it so that whenever the bot sends an embed, the color for it is random. Here's my code:

```
colors = ['0xFFE4E1', '0x00FF7F', '0xD8BFD8', '0xDC143C', '0xFF4500', '0xDEB887', '0xADFF2F', '0x800000', '0x4682B4', '0x006400', '0x808080', '0xA0522D', '0xF08080', '0xC71585', '0xFFB6C1', '0x00CED1']

@client.command(help='Shares a meme')
async def meme(ctx):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("dankmemes")
    all_subs = []
    top = subreddit.top(limit = 75)

    for submission in top:
      all_subs.append(submission)
  
    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)
    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url
    em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = random.choice(colors))

    em.set_image(url = url)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

It gives me this error: `TypeError: Expected discord.Colour, int, or Embed.Empty but received str instead.`

Not sure how to fix this, any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess, it must be

```
colors = [0xFFE4E1, 0x00FF7F, 0xD8BFD8, 0xDC143C, 0xFF4500, 0xDEB887, 0xADFF2F, 0x800000, 0x4682B4, 0x006400, 0x808080, 0xA0522D, 0xF08080, 0xC71585, 0xFFB6C1, 0x00CED1]
```

Comment: ...can't believe I didn't think of this lol. It worked, thanks for your help!

Comment: this works because python interprets hex literals as integers, which is the default input to the `discord.Color` class.

Answer (score 5):

As your error message suggests, the class `discord.Embed` does not accept a string as a valid input for the `color` keyword argument. It must instead be an instance of the class: [`discord.Color`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20colour#colour).

There are several ways to accomplish your task then:

- pass the color as an integer `discord.Colour(value)`
- pass the color as separate r, g, b values: `discord.Colour.from_rgb(r, g, b)`
- hsv: `discord.Colour.from_hsv(h, s, v)`
- or use the built-in random color function: `discord.Colour.random()`

It is also acceptable to just pass the integer directly to `discord.Embed` rather than creating a `discord.Color` object, but the other options will not be available then.

example:

`em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = discord.Colour.random())`

Answer (score 0):

## Random Colors rgb

**I don't know, if it works**

Maybe you can use this:

```
def random_color():
    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)

    rgbl = [r, g, b]
    return tuple(rgbl)
```

You need to import `random` for that

*It was:*

```
em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = random.choice(colors))
```

*Change*:

```
em = discord.Embed(title = name, color = random_color())
```

I use it, to get a random color from the bot in chat:
(173, 435, 243) for example

Comment: The discord.py library itself has a method to generate a random color. Check [Colour.random](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Colour.random).